# I want to stop printing report on last line print

Tags: c#, printing

I have a report for sales the length is dynamic so,I want stop printing on last line 
 by using c # code

Comment: **Generally, when you stop sending information to the printer, it stops printing.** No one can give you a more specific answer until you edit your question to add some clarification. Please provide us with more details about your configuration, how you're generating the report, what code you have so far, what behavior you're currently seeing vs the behavior you *want* to achieve, etc.

Comment: Weird question.  Hard to envision it continue printing after the last line.  Printing in Windows is page based, nothing goes into the printer (or comes out) until the EndPage() function is called.

Answer (score 1):

everybody. I have 1 solution, I hope it is useful for you.

First, you should use a for statement to count number of rows.
Second, you should know font size.

For example : I have 5 rows, font size is 8. And now, i will calculate height of paper size.

```
PaperSize p = new PapaerSize("a","228",Convert.ToInt32((i*28)*0.33333333338))*100);
```

Explain: i*28 ----> font size is 8, once print a row, x coordinator + 20.

```
Convert.ToInt32((i*28)*0.33333333338))*100-----> this will convert from point to inches.
```

Sorry about writing skill.